# Не работает отладка в эмуляторе Андроид

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Использую VS 2017 + Xamarin + VS Emulator for Android

Запускаю на выполнение только что созданный новый проект Single-View App (Android).

На эмуляторе открывается приложение с кнопкой. Кнопка работает, считает клики.

Ставлю точку останова в коде метода OnCreate, перезапускаю проект.

Точка останова красная, но не срабатывает.

То же самое происходит при выносе метода Click в отдельный метод и установки точки останова в нем.

При нажатии кнопки точка останова не играет.

Вопрос:

Как заставить студию видеть точки останова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установка обновлений VS, перезапуск компьютера и adb reboot помогли.
Отладка заработала.